# Capistrano actions: invoke_command vs run?

Tags: capistrano

What the difference between invoke_command and run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `invoke_command` you can use the :via options ot indicate if this has to be invoked by `sudo` or by `run`.  This way you can have a single config file that can do `sudo` or `run` based on a variable (maybe in prod you want `sudo` but in dev you want simple `run`).

So... The `invoke_command` will call `run` by default.

Otherwise, they are identical.

Source: http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/c/capistrano-edge-2.5.6/Capistrano/Configuration/Actions/Invocation.html